# Why this sample ASP.NET + Jquery + javascript custom MVC doesn't show something?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I tried to integrate this javascript mvc sample http://www.alexatnet.com/content/model-view-controller-mvc-javascript into an asp.net page, I'm complete beginner at jquery and nothing shows up, why ?

Update: I have added missing html listbox but now no javascript seems to execute to initialize the listbox nor the buttons seem to work

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="javascriptmvc01._Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">

        /**
        * The Model. Model stores items and notifies
        * observers about changes.
        */
        var ListModel = function (items) {
            this._items = items;
            this._selectedIndex = -1;

            this.itemAdded = new Event(this);
            this.itemRemoved = new Event(this);
            this.selectedIndexChanged = new Event(this);
        };

        ListModel.prototype = {

            getItems: function () {
                return [].concat(this._items);
            },

            addItem: function (item) {
                this._items.push(item);
                this.itemAdded.notify({ item: item });
            },

            removeItemAt: function (index) {
                var item = this._items[index];
                this._items.splice(index, 1);
                this.itemRemoved.notify({ item: item });
                if (index == this._selectedIndex)
                    this.setSelectedIndex(-1);
            },

            getSelectedIndex: function () {
                return this._selectedIndex;
            },

            setSelectedIndex: function (index) {
                var previousIndex = this._selectedIndex;
                this._selectedIndex = index;
                this.selectedIndexChanged.notify({ previous: previousIndex });
            }

        };  


        var Event = function (sender) {
            this._sender = sender;
            this._listeners = [];
        };

        Event.prototype = {
            attach: function (listener) {
                this._listeners.push(listener);
            },
            notify: function (args) {
                for (var i = 0; i < this._listeners.length; i++) {
                    this._listeners[i](this._sender, args);
                }
            }
        };

        var ListView = function (model, controller, elements) {
            this._model = model;
            this._controller = controller;
            this._elements = elements;

            var _this = this;

            // attach model listeners
            this._model.itemAdded.attach(function () {
                _this.rebuildList();
            });
            this._model.itemRemoved.attach(function () {
                _this.rebuildList();
            });

            // attach listeners to HTML controls
            this._elements.list.change(function (e) {
                _this._controller.updateSelected(e);
            });

        };


        ListView.prototype = {

            show: function () {
                this.rebuildList();
                var e = this._elements;
                var _this = this;
                e.addButton.click(function () { _this._controller.addItem() });
                e.delButton.click(function () { _this._controller.delItem() });
            },

            rebuildList: function () {
                var list = this._elements.list;
                list.html('');
                var items = this._model.getItems();
                for (var key in items)
                    list.append($('<option>' + items[key] + '</option>'))
                this._model.setSelectedIndex(-1);
            }

        };

        var ListController = function (model) {
            this._model = model;
        };

        ListController.prototype = {

            addItem: function () {
                var item = prompt('Add item:', '');
                if (item)
                    this._model.addItem(item);
            },

            delItem: function () {
                var index = this._model.getSelectedIndex();
                if (index != -1)
                    this._model.removeItemAt(this._model.getSelectedIndex());
            },

            updateSelected: function (e) {
                this._model.setSelectedIndex(e.target.selectedIndex);
            }

        };

        $(function () {
            var model = new ListModel(['PHP', 'JavaScript']);
            var view = new ListView(model, new ListController(model),
        {
            'list': $('#list'),
            'addButton': $('#plusBtn'),
            'delButton': $('#minusBtn')
        }
    );
            view.show();
        });        
    </script>

<select id="list" size="10" style="width: 15em"></select><br/>
<button id="plusBtn">  +  </button>
<button id="minusBtn">  -  </button>
    </div>



    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change:

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript">
```

to:

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot :) I created by hand that's why I forgot because Visual Studio crashes when I try to drag and drop the script :)

Comment: Nevertheless there is something weird: contrary to the original site, when I add an item, the whole page refresh and so everything reinitialize.

Comment: I think that is due to the `<button>` tags, which operate as submit buttons.  Try changing them to `<input type="button" />`

Answer (score 1):

you don't have the HTML DOM elements in your code anywhere:

```
<select id="list" size="10" style="width: 15em"></select><br/>
<button id="plusBtn">  +  </button>
<button id="minusBtn">  -  </button>
```

these are the elements that are being selected and passed as `'list'`, `'addButton'`, and `'delButton'` when calling `new ListView(..)`.  without them in the document, the javascript doesn't have anything to work with.

Comment: Thanks I have added missing html listbox but now no javascript seems to execute to initialize the listbox nor the buttons seem to work